# Update client windows service with cloud data

Tags: c#, synchronization, cloud, clickonce, message-queue

Users will be able to configure the printer/scanner on a web application.

So I've a windows service running on client machine that communicate to cloud db through API and get the printer/scanner details and configure them accordingly in local network.

The service is configured to run every 30 minutes. So when a user modifies a printer/scanner property using the web application, the update will be available in client machine only after windows service run once. So the maximum time delay will be 30 minutes as the windows service is configure to run every 30 minutes.

Windows service cannot invoke API frequently as there will be too much load on the web server and also the update doesn't happen often but when it happens, customer expects their local network printer/scanner to be updated immediately with new configuration.

So, the question here is how effectively I could update the cloud data to the local service so that they will be in sync as soon as possible.

Please share if there is any other way to achieve this.

I've heard about message queue/clickone but I am not sure how it could suit here